# postorius modifies web path - content of page not reachable

Tags: mailman

need some help please.

I installed mailman3 and mailman3-web and all the related stuff using `apt install ..` .
The mailman backend seems to work properly. Trying to access the web frontent "postorius" just gives me the starting page showing the postorius logo and some Links to "Lists", "Achives" and so on and an error message in a red box: "This page either doesn't exist, or it moved somewhere else."

my url is : http://my.host/mailman3/postorius/lists/

Looking at the links in the page head leads me to a slightly different url .. http://my.host/mailman/postorius/lists/ . ( missing '3' with mailman)  Clicking these links leads to an 404 error.

Why is postorius changing the root directory from mailman3 to mailman ?  Of course, these links are not reachable.

I thaugt, this path name  was somwhere linked hardcoded. So I changed the apache config to use the root path /mailman/  instead of /mailman3/ . But what happens is: the path given by postorius is now /mailma/.. missing "n" at the end.

How can I fix this ?  I don't have any knowledge about programming in python, so I can't debug it myself ..

thanks for any suggestion

Mike

Ubuntu 20.04.3
mailman 3.3.2

Comment: I found the solution in this thread: https://lists.mailman3.org/archives/list/mailman-users@mailman3.org/thread/JSLTGUQDWRGQTOZWUKIOSDJLJSDYMSUC/#MFGF7SHUJBAC4VRCMULHNGUHD5ODTE4K

Comment: You can post it as an answer. Be sure to describe the steps and add the link as source but please don't post link only.